# How to get the embedded filename of a GPG encrypted file

Tags: gpg

One can see the embedded filename of an encrypted file using `gpg --list-packets 001.gpg`, which shows:

```
[...]

:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1630584912, name="elephant.jpg",
    raw data: 87417 bytes

[...]
```

Is there a way to get the embedded filename only? Is there a command that displays `elephant.jpg` only?

Answer (score 3):

To get the data between `name="` and `",` on the line after the line saying `:literal data packet:`, using `sed`:

```bsh
gpg --list-packets file.gpg |
sed -e '/^:literal data packet:$/!d' \
    -e 'N' \
    -e 's/[^=]*name="//' \
    -e 's/",$//' \
    -e 'q'
```

The `sed` expressions first deletes all lines read from `gpg` until it finds the `:literal data packet:` line.  It then immediately appends the next line with `N` and removes everything now in the buffer up to and including the first `name="` substring.  It then removes `",` from the end of the line and quits (outputting what's remaining in the buffer).

This allows us to handle filenames like `file",` or `name="hello"` embedded in the `gpg` data.

Note that special characters will be encoded as a hexadecimal escape sequence before they are embedded in the `gpg` file.  For example, every newline character will be encoded as `\x0a`.

Answer (score 2):

You could `sed` the pattern to extract the filename:

```
$ text='
[...]

:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1630584912, name="elephant.jpg",
    raw data: 87417 bytes

[...]
'
$ echo "$text" | sed -n 's/.*name="\(.*\)",/\1/p'
elephant.jpg
$
```

Comment: Nice answer. I have something for those who prefer grep with lookarounds: `grep -Po '(?<=name=").*(?=",$)'`.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be, I imagine, to use the gpg library and do the same thing that the CLI utility does.

Otherwise you could filter gpg output:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "No filename specified" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
if [ ! -r "$1" ]; then
    echo "File not found" 1>&2
    exit 2
fi
gpg --list-packets "$1" \
    | grep ", name=" | cut -f2 -d '"'
```

(This assumes that the embedded name does not contain double quotes).

Answer (score 0):

A short version:

```
gpg --list-packets file.gpg | awk -F\" '/created/ {print $2}'
```